# Сколько Event.ENTER_FRAME в 1 секунде?

Tags: actionscript

Друзья, кто знает, сколько Event.ENTER_FRAME в 1 секунде? 
Такое ощущение, что это количество тактов в процессоре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Иполнительная часть FlashPlayer или AIR платформы основана на покадровом выводе графических экземпляров (Sprite, Shape, MovieClip). Например, если есть движение таких объектов между кадрами или векторная анимация в MovieClip, то перед отображением кадра среда выполняет перерисовку таких элементов. Хотя такое состояние может быть и переопределено, например, в Starling библиотеке каждый кадр происходит полная отрисовка сцены.
- Это событие рассылается после выполнения и отрисовки предыдущего кадра.
- Количество тактов процессора ни при чем.
- Зависит от начальных установок в SWF файле (байткоде), например, если там стоит 30FPS, то больше 30 рассылок ENTER_FRAME в 1 секунду быть не может.
- А вот меньше быть может, например, если большое количество графики нужно было вывести на экран или код, выполняемый до этого момента, был достаточно тяжелым. SWF Приложение вполне может ждать десятки секунд до выполнения следующего кадра.

Answer (score 1):

Количество фреймов в секунду - FPS. Задается в свойствах проекта Adobe Flash.